# WPF app behavior depending on windows user access level

Tags: wpf, performance

I have developed a WPF app (ef, MVVM) and realized that the performance of the app varies depending on the Windows user that is logged in. I tested this in a Windows 7 POSready machine that has 2 users.

For a user with admin rights, the application works great. But if I log in as a regular user the performance goes down. I have no idea why this is happening. Anybody knows something about this?

Comment: What does the application do? You don't give much to go on.

Comment: The application is a pos system, which has a webservice. I'm using .net framework 4.5, as db I can choose between ce and sql express. Nothing really special.

Comment: I think it has to do with ce dbs. With sql express the performance is good with both users. Any idea?

Comment: I would suggest that you profile your application running under both users, to identify what part of the code is under-performing.

Comment: Is the location where the CE database is saved for both users - is the same place?

Comment: Maybe there is some UAC magic involved (folder redirection) that degrades performance.

Comment: I would go with Dan Puzey May's idea and if you have unit tests with mocks for external components like database access and others then I would also say to try to execute them with different access levels that may tell you which part of code is heavy maybe its the external component but profiling can yield to quick detection of the issue

Comment: You should use a performance analysis tool to find out what methods exactly degrade in performance. then it should be much easier to find the reason for that behavior.

Comment: Rights might be an issue, specifically disk rights. Maybe your regular user doesn't have rights to a directory. You don't crash but you're wasting time in an error condition.

Comment: Performance of what? I would down vote this question for being vague, but it's not worth giving up my rep points.

Comment: @xr280xr downvoting a question doesn't cost rep points anymore (it does cost points on answers though)

Answer (score 0):

I experienced once this situation and the situation once I turned of the windows default logging.